# How can I test this buried callback function?

Tags: jasmine

I'm was able to figure out how to test the this.toJSON function by binding to the click function. But I'm a little lost in how to test the this.download() function. (this is AmCharts related, custom exports)

```js
it('should call toJSON on export', function() {
    var exp = chart.export.menu[0].menu[0].menu[0];

    /*
        exp = {
            label: 'JSON',
            click: function() {
                this.toJSON({}, function(data) {
                    this.download(
                        data,
                        'application/json',
                        this.setup.chart.$exportName + '.json'
                    );
                });
            }
        }
    */

    var self = { toJSON: jasmine.createSpy() };
    exp.click.bind(self)();

    expect(exp.label).toEqual('toJSON');
    expect(self.toJSON).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while of getting my head around all the different contexts for this, This seems to work well for me...

```js
// before each I set everything up
var dlcb = {
    setup: {
        chart: chart
    },
    download: jasmine.createSpy('download')
};

var self = {};
['toCSV', 'toJSON', 'toXLSX'].forEach(function(name) {
    self[name] = jasmine
        .createSpy(name, function(a, cb) {
            cb.bind(dlcb)(true);
        })
        .and.callThrough();
});

// -----

it('should call toJSON on export', function() {
    var exp = chart.export.menu[0].menu[0].menu[0];

    /*
        exp = {
            label: 'JSON',
            click: function() {
                this.toJSON({}, function(data) {
                    this.download(
                        data,
                        'application/json',
                        this.setup.chart.$exportName + '.json'
                    );
                });
            }
        }
    */

    var self = { toJSON: jasmine.createSpy() };
    exp.click.bind(self)();

    expect(exp.label).toEqual('toJSON');
    expect(self.toJSON).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(dlcb.download).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true, 'application/json', 'vp-chart-export.json');
});
```